# Does this factor into a dot product

Tags: vectors, factoring

A hopefully easy question.  I have this:

$$c^2+(x^2+y^2+z^2)(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)-2c(x*v_x+y*v_y+z*v_z)$$

And I was wondering if this somehow factors into 
$$(c-f(\vec{r}, \vec{v}))^2 $$
where

$$f(\vec{r}, \vec{v})=x*v_x+y*v_y+z*v_z=\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v} $$ 
 $$f(\vec{r}, \vec{v})^2=(x^2+y^2+z^2)(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)=(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r})(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}) $$

Does such a function exist?  Can such a function exist?  Or am I stuck with this being the most compact form:
$ c^2 + (\vec{r} \cdot \vec{r})(\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v})-2c(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v}) $
or $ c^2 + r^2v^2-2c(\vec{r} \cdot \vec{v})
$

Answer (score 0):

Expand the quadratic in powers of $c$ and equate coefficients
$$(c-f(\vec{r}, \vec{v}))^2 =c^2-2cf(\vec{r}, \vec{v})+\left(f(\vec{r}, \vec{v}) \right)^2$$

$$=c^2 -2c(\vec r \cdot \vec v)+(\vec r \cdot \vec r)(\vec v \cdot \vec v)$$

this is only possible if
$$(\vec r \cdot \vec v)^2=(\vec r \cdot \vec r)(\vec v \cdot \vec v)$$

Which only happens when the vectors $\vec r$ and $\vec v$ are either parallel or antiparallel, in which case $f(\vec{r}, \vec{v})=\vec{r} \cdot  \vec{v}$